# Logging in to my site opens a new tab?

Tags: asp.net, html, http

I've been working on my personal website as of late, and even thought it's not a big problem because I'm the only one that sees it, it's annoying nonetheless.

Whenever I go to my login page, it all works fine. If I enter a bad username/password, it will just print a simple text message error(intended). But, if I login correctly, then instead of redirecting to the root of my website as I intend, it will instead create a new tab in firefox and from there it will be in `/` (which is correct). The problem is why does it create a new tab? I didn't even think forms were capable of such a thing:

My full login page is at http://lastyearswishes.com/login The gist of it is:

```
<form method="post" target="/login">
    Username: <input type="text" name="username" /> <br />
    Password: <input type="password" name="password" /> <br />
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" />
</form>
```

And my server side code is also very simple:

```
if(RouteID=="login"){           
  if(AuthenticationModule.Login(Form["username"],Form["password"],false)){
    //logged in correctly
    Response.Redirect("/"); //just go to the root of my site
  }else{
    Write("You fail at life");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

«`target="/login"`» means "open in window named «`/login`»". If it doesn't exist, a new one is opened. I think you meant to use

```
<form method="post" action="/login">
```

[HTML Form Element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.3)

Comment: Oh wow. I feel stupid. I can't believe that was right under me and I didn't see it. Sometimes it just takes a second pair of eyes I guess :)